# Distributing points evenly on a sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I am looking for an algorithm to put $n$-points on a sphere, so that the minimum distance between any two points is as large as possible.

I have found some related questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere) but those algorithms are not an exact solution more random distributions. For special number of points (inscribed Platonic solids) it is clear but how about 5 points for example. I would be grateful for hints to the literature.

Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: This problem is unsolved for large number of points.

Comment: For a couple of related papers, see arXiv:math.MG/0611451 and arXiv:math/0607446.

Comment: 5 points is a strange case: the optimal distance is no better than it is for 6 (so an optimal arrangement can be gotten by taking the 6-point arrangement and deleting a point). See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208484/packing-obtuse-vectors-in-mathbbrd/208486#208486.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is considerable literature on this question, and closely related variations.
See:

- The [*Thompson problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem): Which configurations of $n$ electrons on a sphere minimize the electrostatic potential energy?
- The [*Tammes problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammes_problem): Which configurations of $n$ points on a sphere maximize the smallest distance between any two points? Sometimes phrased as packing $n$ congruent circles on a sphere:

---

[image: DiskPacking]

          

<sup>(Image from [Paul Sutcliffe](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0pms/my-projects/proj4_1213.html).)</sup>

---

According to

> Musin, Oleg R., and Alexey S. Tarasov. "The Tammes problem for $N=14$." [arXiv:1410.2536 Abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2536) (2014).

the Tammes problem is solved exactly for

- For $n=3,4,6,12$ by L. Fejes Toth (1943).
- For $n=5,7,8,9$ by Schütte and van der Waerden (1951).
- For $n=10,11$ by Danzer (1963). **Added** (*8Sep15*): Exact radius for $n=10$ by Sugimoto & Tanemura.
- For $n=24$ by Robinson (1961).
- For $n=13, 14$ by Musin and Tarasov (2014).

  ---

  [image: N=14.]

            

  <sup>Fig.1 from Musin & Tarasov: $n=14$.</sup>

  ---

  **Added** (*8Sep15*): The exact radius for $n=10$ was just found:

> Teruhisa Sugimoto, Masaharu Tanemura.
>   "Exact value of Tammes problem for N=10." Sep 2015.
>   [arXiv 1509.01768 Abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01768).

---

[image: STFig1b]

          

<sup>Fig.1b from Sugimoto & Tanemura.</sup>

---

**Added** (*31Dec2017*) in response to a question by @R_Berger:
For $n=20$, the best arrangement for the Tammes problem is not
the dodecahedron's vertices.
The optimal is unknown, but this beats the dodecahedron:

---

[image: DodecaTammes]

          

<sup>Coordinates from [Neil Sloane link](http://neilsloane.com/packings/dim3/),
due to  R.H. Hardin, N.J.A. Sloane & W.D. Smith (1994).</sup>

---

Comment: There is a problem similar to the Thompson problem, which is to find the minimum potential energy of a continuous charge distribution on a nonspherical conductor. There is a surprising set of exact solutions for some special shapes, in which the charge density is proportional to the fourth root of the absolute value of the Gaussian curvature. I W McAllister 1990 J. Phys. D: Appl. Phys. 23 359 doi:10.1088/0022-3727/23/3/016

Comment: @BenCrowell: Nice! (McAllister, I. W. "Conductor curvature and surface charge density." *Journal of Physics. D*, Applied Physics 23.3 (1990): 359-362.) That *anything* interesting is the $4$-th root of the curvature is amazing.

Comment: What's most surprising to me is that there is a link between a global property extrinsic to the surface (energy) and a local, intrinsic property (curvature).

Comment: $n=20$ is not a dodecahedron, why not and who solved that?

Comment: @Rudi_Birnbaum It suffices to check that two closest vertices in a dodecahedron (inscribed in the sphere) are at a distance closer than $0.647046$, since one can give a spherical code with separation larger than this (see https://neilsloane.com/packings/).

Answer (score 14):

Since you are asking about an algorithmic perspective, I wanted to point out that a closely related variation (with logarithmic potential instead of hard core potential) is the subject of one of Smale's "[Mathematical Problems for the
Next Century](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fbf03025291)." In Problem 7, Smale asks if there is a polynomial time algorithm ([in a particular model of computation over real numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186226/the-link-and-equivalence-between-variant-definition-of-computation-model-and-com)) to place $N$ points on the sphere so that the total energy is $O(\log N)$ above the minimum energy.

Now, for specific finite values of $N$, Neil Sloane has a table of best known spherical codes with references: http://neilsloane.com/packings/

Answer (score 7):

There is a rather comprehensive list of research articles about points on spheres and manifolds at https://my.vanderbilt.edu/edsaff/spheres-manifolds/

A nice paper is E. B. Saff, A. B. J. Kuijlaars, "Distributing Many Points on a Sphere", The Mathematical Intelligencer, Winter 1997, Volume 19, Issue 1, pp 5-11.