# Sets of points avoiding small angles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

**(1)** $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'd like to place $n$ points in the plane so that the smallest angle they
determine is as large as possible.
In a sense, such a point set is in very general position, not only
avoiding three points collinear, but also avoiding near collinearities.

Define the smallest angle of a set $S$ of points to the be smallest angle
of any triangle formed by three points in $S$. So the $n=4$ and $n=5$ point
sets shown below have smallest angles $45^\circ$ and $36^\circ$ respectively.

---

[image: PtsNoSmallAngs]

---

> ***Q1***. What is the maximum of the smallest angle determined by any set $S$ of $n$ points, the maximum over all $S$? Is $S$ the vertices of a regular $n$-gon?

*Update*. Answered *Yes* by fedja with a nice proof in the comments.

**(2)** $\mathbb{R}^3$ (*Added*).

In 3D, the optimal arrangement seems to be akin to 
packing points on a sphere, e.g., the 
[Tammes problem or the Thompson problem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/212556/6094).
Below shows the smallest angle
realized by the $12$ vertices of the icosahedron.

---

[image: IcosaSmallAng]

          

<sup>Smallest angle $\approx 31.7^\circ$.</sup>

---

> ***Q2***. The same question in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d>3$.

Likely this question has been
studied, in which case pointers to the literature would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the vertices of an $n$-gon. Take the smallest inner angle of the convex hull and see how it is divided into $n-2$ angles by the rays from the corresponding vertex to all other points to show that $\pi/n$ or less is always there.

Comment: The problem can also be studied on the sphere, where circles through the north pole correspond to lines in the plane under [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection), as that mapping is conformal, the intersection angles of circles on the sphere and between lines in the plane are the same.

Comment: Of course the stereographic projection equivalence generalizes to higher dimensions; the points on a regular n-gon, when centered at the origin, can be interpreted as the images of points on a sphere with its south pole at the origin, where the points have equal latitude and are evenly distributed. The analogue, when going to higher dimension n, would be an even distribution of the points in the intersection of an $n$-sphere with a hyperplane of dimension $n$, that is parallel to $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. on a $n-1$-sphere, thus supporting your assumption the projection is also an $n-1$ sphere.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Thanks, but I don't see how to actually compute the optimal arrangement in 3D for arbitrary $n$, using the stereographic projection viewpoint. Perhaps it is like packing points on a sphere, with no clear theory except for special values of $n$.