# Packing disks of infinitesimal diameter on a sphere: the asymptotics of the Tammes problem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

This is an elaboration on [MO Question 212550](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere): given $ 0 < 2a << 1 $, how many points can be placed on the unit sphere, subject to the constraint that any two of these points must be at Euclidean distance at least $2a$ ?

Obviously, every point must be allocated at least the area of a disk with radius $a$, so the maximum number $M(a)$ cannot exceed $4/a^2$; however, Fejes Tóth famously proved that the allocated area must be at least that of the circumscribing hexagon, so that: 
 $2 \sqrt 3 a^2 M(a) = 4\pi - S(a)$ with $S(a) > {2\over3}\pi a^2 $.

Then, we have a 1955 (**Edit:** 1951) paper by Habicht & Van der Waerden offering a very contorted construction, and the estimate: 
$S(a) = O(a^{2/3}) $. They concluded with an oddly phrased comment, acknowledging their explicit value for the constant is far from minimal, while implying the order of magnitude is tight, i. e. their $O(a^{2/3}) $ should really be $\Theta(a^{2/3}) $.

Then... that's all. Or at least, that's all I could google regarding my question. To wit:

How much is proven, and how much more is plausible, of the behaviour of $S(a)\over a^{2/3}$ for inifinitesimal $ a $? If it is $o(1) $, what is its order of magnitude? If it is   $\Theta(1) $, what are its upper & lower limits?

**Edit**: I do not mean Google has no answer to this question; only that they lack relevance. J. Park pointed out in his answer that any explicit construction provides a lower bound; a plethora of such constructions result in $S(a) < C a^{2/3}$ for various $C$'s, some better, some worse than the original one by H.-v.d.W. What's wanting is a public claim of optimality.

Comment: You might be able to get something useful from results on Riesz energy minimizing point configurations e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4037 in the limit $s\to\infty$.

Comment: If you have access to MathSciNet, that might be an improvement on Google.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus: Maybe this warning from the hlinked paper, that Riesz s-energy is a red herring: "Since for s ≥ d the s-energy integral for every positive Borel
probability measure supported on $S^d$ is +∞, potential theory fails to work.". Does it qualify as useful?

Answer (score 7):

The second-order behavior of $M(a)$ for $\mathbb{S}^2$ was investigated in van der Waerden's paper *[Punkte auf der Kugel](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=50912)* shortly after the first paper by Habicht and van der Waerden was published (*[Lagerung von Punkten aut der Kugel](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0042730)* appears to be the paper you are referring to, although it was published in 1951).

There is only an improved lower bound for $M(a)$ given in the later paper (one needs also to renormalize quantities there to agree with those in this question).

**Edit**: Note that any construction gives a lower bound on $M(a)$. It is difficult to give asymptotically optimal constructions to the first order (see Chapter 3.3 of  Hamkin's thesis [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.97&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a review of lower bounds). Fejes Tóth's upper bound gives to first order a comparable bound (for $d=2a$):

$$M(d)\leq 2\left[1-\frac{\pi/6}{\cot^{-1}\sqrt{3-d^2}}\right]^{-1}.$$

It is not clear whether there are matching bounds known to the second order.

Comment: That paper indeed; 1951 not 1955, my mistake. I believe they provide a lower bound, not an upper bound, for $M$ as a function of $a$. Their formula (17) maximizes $a$ for a fixed $M$, in my notations; two quantities they named $1/R$ and $N$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, this difference between the two papers was overlooked. It is fixed above now.